# pointer to parent changes for no reason

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have two classes say A & B like this:

```
// A.h
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

#include "B.h"

class A {
public:
    std::vector<B> bVec;
    A();
    void foo();
virtual ~A();
};
#endif /* A_H_ */

//--------------------
// A.cpp
#include "A.h"

A::A() {
    B b(this);
    bVec.push_back(b);
}

void A::foo() {
    for(int i=0; i<bVec.size(); i++)
        bVec[i].addNewB();
}

A::~A() {
}


//--------------------
// B.h

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#ifndef B_H_
#define B_H_

class A;

class B {
public:

    A* parent;
    double data[15];

    B(A* p);
    void addNewB();
    virtual ~B();
};

#endif /* B_H_ */

//--------------------
// B.cpp

#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

B::B(A* p) {
    parent = p;
}

void B::addNewB() {
    A* tmpA = parent;
    if(parent->bVec.size() < 3)
    {
        std::cout<< "Before: " << parent->bVec.size() << '\n';
        parent->bVec.push_back(B(parent));
        std::cout<< "After: " << parent->bVec.size() << '\n';
    }
    if(tmpA == parent)
        cout<< "parent the same\n";
    else
        cout<< "parent changed\n";
}

B::~B() {
}

//--------------------
// main.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "A.h"

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo();
    std::cout<< "finish\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code I get these results:

> Before: 1
>
> After: 16276538888567495168
>
> parent changed
>
> Before: 2
>
> After: 3
>
> parent the same
>
> parent the same
>
> finish

The problem as you can see is that sometimes the parent pointer changes after push_back. I tried debugging the code right before and after push_back I checked parent pointer. Before that it's some address but after that it's something else plus this text:  which seems to have something with segmentation fault.

The key to the problem here seems to be the size of each instance of B. If I change the size of 'data' to anything below 14 the program works fine but for 14 or higher this happens.

This looks very weird and I've spent days struggling with it. Can you tell me why this is happening?

Comment: `parent` doesn't point to a valid `A` object.

Comment: Do you initialize the parent pointer?

Comment: Bad design: `parent->bVec.push_back(B()` - B() has no parent

Comment: I have completely revised the question and these comments belong to the old version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void B::addNewB() {
    A* tmpA = parent;
    if(parent->bVec.size() < 3)
    {
        std::cout<< "Before: " << parent->bVec.size() << '\n';
        parent->bVec.push_back(B(parent));
        std::cout<< "After: " << parent->bVec.size() << '\n';
    }
    if(tmpA == parent)
        cout<< "parent the same\n";
    else
        cout<< "parent changed\n";
}
```

bVec is changed here, which contains the `this` for a particular `B` object that is running code.

```
void A::foo() {
    for(int i=0; i<bVec.size(); i++)
        bVec[i].addNewB();
}
```

`bVec` is changed on this call.  On `push_back()` calls that exceed the preallocated heap space (like this one probably), `vector` needs to reallocate heap memory and move everything over.  During the move, `vector` destroyed the `B` object running that code.  Control was restored to the `B` code with the outdated `this`, and thus `this->parent` now contained garbage.

Here's what a backtrace probably looks like:

```
A::foo()
B::addNewB()
vector<B>::reallocate() //destroys previous frame's B
```

Comment: So whenever vector runs out of space it reallocates everything even if I reserve some space and my only solution is to reserve the maximum possible from the start right?

Comment: @ soroosh.strife Or store pointers to `B` objects on the heap with `vector<B*> bVec` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A vector allocates more space than what `size()` suggest, you can find 
out with `capacity()`, and change with `reserve()`. This means, when 
you `push_back()` there is room to grow in. When that space runs out, 
the whole vector reallocates more space, this process moves existing 
objects in memory. This is why you get pointers that point to objects that 
are no longer there. 
A vector always keeps all its objects continuously (sequentially) in memory.

One possible solution would be to `reserve` enough space so that a 
reallocation never happens, another to switch to `std::list`.

Also note that it is not just you parent pointer that gets invalidated, since
you 
are triggering the vector reallocation from a method for an object in said vector, 
you also use an invalidated `this` pointer.

Comment: "A vector always keeps all its objects continuously in memory."  I'm not sure how to interpret this last statement, aside from the self evident "things in memory are things in memory."

Comment: @Aggieboy Continuously as in one right after the other, not continuously as in all the time.The objects are lumped together in one block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `parent` pointer changes. As far as I can see the error is that in `foo()` you iterate through `bVec` calling `size()` on it in each iteration, while the size of `bVec` changes after call to `addNewB`.

Comment: You're right that I hadn't noticed that my comparing to size is problematic. But I took a back up of the pointer and checked it with the one after push_back and it was different.

Comment: You should provide a code where you compare pointers and they are different if this question is valuable for you. For me it looks like you forgot to initialize some pointer.

Comment: I rephrased the question and added runable code. Please take another look.